# Extend Mahout for new dataset

Tags: mahout, datamodel, mahout-recommender

I want to build a recommendation model based on Mahout. My dataset format has extra columns  other than userID, itemID, rating and timestamp. Thus, I think I need to extend the 
FileDataModel.

I looked into **JesterDataModel** as an example. However, I have a problem with the logic flow. In its **buildModel()** method, an empty map "data" is first constructed. It is then thrown into processFile. I assume that "data" is modified in this method, since later it is used to construct the GenericDataModel However, data is a local variable instead of a class variable, so how is it modified?

```
processFile(iterator, data, timestamps, false);
return new GenericDataModel(GenericDataModel.toDataMap(data, true));
```

Comment: What do you want to do with this extra columns?

Comment: @Julian For example, each user reads a book, rates it, and adds some tags. The extra columns are the tags. When recommend a book to a user, I would also like to see if the book's tags matches the user's. Of course I can create another data structure to store these tag preference, but ideally, I want to wrap up all the things into the DataModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see... I believe you would have to rewrite major parts like DataModel, Similarities calculation, and so on and so on, to make that work. You can look at the `Rescorer` which allows you to introduce your own logic and filter items out or boost some other items based on your requirements.

In chapter 5 of the Mahout in Action book there is an example of how to use the `Rescorer` class. You can see the code here [(link)](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/tree/master/src/main/java/mia/recommender/ch05)