# Getting preference based on user data

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, classification, mahout

I have user data for an airline travel agency, from this data I want to get the most preferred value  of certain entities for a user. My data set is of the format like-

```
userId  From      TO        Meal    Carrier            Travel type

MT001   London    Abu Dhabi Non Veg Lufthansa          International
MT001   Abu Dhabi Beijing   Veg     Lufthansa          International
MT001   New York  Chicago   Non Veg American Airlines  Domestic
MT002   New York  Texas     Veg     American Airlines  Domestic
```

Now I want to get the preferred value of user MT001 for meal,carrier column and classify this user. I know we can get these values using SQL, but is it possible to do it using mahout framework? I do not want to get the result in real time, I am thinking of something like a batch job which pre process the data and stores the result somewhere from where we can fetch the result instantly.

I know that mahout supports classification and can we get the preferred values using something like item based recommendation. Also I am planning to shift to hadoop, so how good of choice mahout will be in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for here is something like content based recommendation, Mahout do supports content based recommendation but I am not sure if its the best framework to implement it, you will have to rewrite a hell lot classes for that to work according to your program.

Found this -[Extend Mahout for new dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555097/extend-mahout-for-new-dataset)